# How to define object in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to assign a value to an object, but when I try to display it always returns `[]`.
here is a piece of my code

```
const exspress = require("express");
const aplication = exspress();
//body parser for informaton monggo
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
//configuration for node aplication
aplication.use(
  bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
const mongose = require("mongoose");

const router = exspress.Router();

const PingModel = mongose.model("Ping");

const ping = require("ping");
var tcpp = require("tcp-ping");     
var obj = Array();
        var a = 0;
        var b = pingtime;
        for(a; a<b; a++){
        ping.promise.probe(host).then(function(data) {
            const storePing = new PingModel();
            storePing.hostPing = host;
            storePing.hostIp = data.numeric_host;
            if (data.alive) {
              storePing.hostStatus = "Ok";
            } else {
              storePing.hostStatus = "Not_ok";
            }
            if (data.alive) {
              storePing.hostLatency = "true";
            } else {
              storePing.hostLatency = "false";
            }
            storePing.save();
            window.obj = storePing
            // return this.obj[a] = storePing;
          });
          console.log(obj);
        }
 module.exports = router;
```

Can you guys tell me how to define an object and fill it with data/value that I use it in separate code/function?

Comment: btw i want to console.log(obj) that  i define var 0bj = Array();

Comment: `window.obj = storePing` what is `window`?

Comment: trying to define as global object , but it did'nt work

Answer (score 0):

try changing `window.obj` to `obj` as your `obj` is only a variable, it is not on a `window` object

also, when declaring your object, you have declared it as an Array.  If you want an Object, you can use `var obj = {};`, though are are reassigning it anyway with `storePing`

also, you would need to move your `console.log` into the `then` callback of the promise, since it is async code you have - at the minute, your `console.log` will fire before the `then` callback of the promise has executed and thus `obj` would not yet have the value your are expecting

Something a long the lines of -

```
const router = exspress.Router();

const PingModel = mongose.model("Ping");

const ping = require("ping");
var tcpp = require("tcp-ping");     
var obj = {}; // NOTE, object instead of array, though this gets reassigned anyway, so doesn't really matter
        var a = 0;
        var b = pingtime;
        for(a; a<b; a++){
        ping.promise.probe(host).then(function(data) {
            const storePing = new PingModel();
            storePing.hostPing = host;
            storePing.hostIp = data.numeric_host;
            if (data.alive) {
              storePing.hostStatus = "Ok";
            } else {
              storePing.hostStatus = "Not_ok";
            }
            if (data.alive) {
              storePing.hostLatency = "true";
            } else {
              storePing.hostLatency = "false";
            }
            storePing.save();
            obj = storePing // <-- NOTE, no window object

            console.log(obj); // <-- NOTE, logging inside the then callback
            // return this.obj[a] = storePing;
          });
        }
 module.exports = router;
```

Comment: its return "{}" dude , i don't know why? or is because i'm trying to assign inside for loop and inside ping.promise.probe function maybe?

Comment: I think you need to await something

Comment: can you update your question with your latest code?

Comment: or how to store .then resut to a variable/object?